# Could not resolve host: 1L9ZSTKURF.algolia.net

Tags: php, laravel, algolia

I have been using Algolia Trial version in Laravel , now it gives error `Could not resolve host: 1L9ZSTKURF.algolia.net` during `Registration` and `logout`
[image]

Comment: Where have you placed that hostname? In a configuration file? Were you supposed to specify the protocol (i.e. `https://`) as well?

Comment: @Martin Bean i specified it in `.env` file

Comment: And does it include the protocol…?

Comment: @MartinBean no..

Comment: Then try adding it.

Answer (score 0):

## Host unreachable - Algolia

Using the simple `ping` to `1L9ZSTKURF.algolia.net` also says that it couldn't resolve host.
It only means it cannot establish connection to that host, so it might be down or it might not even exist.

Just wait for some time or make sure it is on and active.

> **Note** - it seems that Algolia has been having problems with DNS records for new accounts.

Should work after a couple of hours.

**UPDATE 1** check this link for [algolia docs](https://laravel.com/docs/scout) also go check their FAQ on [algolia.com](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/) where you can find about deleting your account and applications' data.

To delete the objects in an index, use `clearIndex`:

```
index.clearIndex();
```

**UPDATE 2**
Algolia is not actually "installed" as is, you need to remove all the algolia tags, very easy way. (`Algolia head block`)

Are you using "Magento"?

Comment: how can I remove algolia from my project.I no longer need it.

Comment: Check "UPDATE 1"

Comment: Check "UPDATE 2"

Comment: I am using Laravel(PHP framework).I have installed it through composer.here it is: [algolia-laravel](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-laravel)

Comment: Check about deleting the head.

Comment: Hello @luismiguelss i am getting this issue when i am trying to connect my Magento 1 With agolio on server 

on my local, it's working fine can you guide me for this?